# Filtering Row values with Data.Table when reading in from online file?

Tags: r, data.table, fread

Working on reading in some taxi data but I want to filter out some rows based on their value and I'm curious if this is possible with data.table. In TLC trip data found here http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml
there is a column labeled "trip distance" that I would like to filter out zeros. Is it possible to call this from fread?

Below is the script I'm working with:

```
library(data.table)

#create your vector to feed into a reading function-----------------------
site_list = NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(i)
site = paste0("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2016-0",i,".csv") 
site_list = rbind(site_list, site)
}
site_list

#read in data--------------------------------------------
#pick your features
featurez = c("tpep_dropoff_datetime", "dropoff_longitude", "dropoff_latitude")
master_taxi = NULL
for (i in site_list) {
master = fread(i, select = featurez)
master_taxi = rbind(master_taxi, master)
}
```

So above I filter out the columns I want, and I don't include trip distance. I could read in the column "trip_distance" and then eliminate the zeros after the fact but I rather not waste the memory and computing power on that. Anyway to push out that parameter through fread?

EDIT******

Frank mentioned it wasn't clear what I wanted to do, so I figured I'd elaborate below. I would like to pass a parameter as such:

```
#read in data--------------------------------------------
#pick your features
featurez = c("tpep_dropoff_datetime", "dropoff_longitude", "dropoff_latitude")
master_taxi = NULL
for (i in site_list) {
master = fread(i, select = featurez, [***variable parameter example: trip_distance >0])
master_taxi = rbind(master_taxi, master)
}
```

Comment: Fyi, general advice in R is: don't grow things in a loop. (I can't help with the substance of your question, since I don't understand it.)

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, need to start moving away from the loops. I've added an edit to hopefully clarify the question a bit.

Comment: Ok, I guess the way I approach this is always `rbindlist(lapply(site_list, fread))[ trip_distance > 0 ]` If memory was a concern then I'd write a more elaborate function for the `lapply`, maybe like `rbindlist(lapply(site_list, function(s) fread(s)[ trip_distance > 0 ]))`. I don't think `fread` supports filtering during the read, but I could be wrong.